# How to use GITHUB_TOKEN to clone a private repository?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

This is my action script:

```
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - run: |
       whoami
       sudo mkdir /first_org
       sudo chmod -R 777 /first_org
       cd /first_org
       git clone https://github.com/first_org/site
       sudo rm -rf /first_org/site/.git
       sudo mkdir /second_org
       sudo chmod -R 777 /second_org
       cd /second_org
       git clone https://github.com/second_org/site
       cp -a /first_org/site/. /second_org/site
       cd /second_org/site
       sudo apt-get update
       sudo apt install nodejs
       npm build
```

The `/first_org/site` is a public repo, but the `/second_org/site` is a private repo.

I don't use `action/checkout@v2` because it doesn't let us specify an **ABSOLUTE** path to clone into. Thus I had to use pure shell commands.

This action belongs to `/second_org/site` repo, thus based on [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow), I can use `GITHUB_TOKEN` to access it. But none of the examples show how can I use it in a simple `git clone` command.

How can I use `GITHUB_TOKEN` in my shell?

Answer (score 5):

You can clone using a token that way in shell (bash):

`git clone https://<token>@github.com/<owner>/<repoName>.git`

Note that the `GITHUB_TOKEN` might not have enough scope permission to be used on private repo. In that case, you will need to use a PAT.

Here is an example of an action I created cloning a repo in bash (as reference): https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/create-other-repo-branch-action/blob/main/action.yml